# Cache issue in flutter web after publishing

Tags: flutter, caching

When I publish new update for my flutter website, I need to remove browser history for reflecting the updates.

index.html

```
<script>
  function clearBrowserCache() {
    caches.delete('your_cache_name').then(function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });
  }
 </script>
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
   // Your Flutter app initialization code

   // Call the clearBrowserCache function when needed.
   js.context.callMethod('clearBrowserCache');
 }
```

I tried these code but its not working.